# Display webpage from desktop application (Minecraft authentication)

Tags: webview

In this question I'm only asking what minecraft launcher uses to display the login webpage.

I am not asking for any clarification on how to log the user in, or anything related to that matter.

//Note that it probably does NOT use javafx

What software could be used to display a webpage or what exactly does minecraft use to display the authentication webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge Legacy WebView

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).